# Is it possible to supply a type converter for a static resource in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, ria, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to style a `LineSeries` chart that has `DateTime` objects on its independent axis and integer values in its dependent axis. I want to show a tooltip text whenever a user overs his mouse on a `DataPoint`, showing both its independent and dependent values, but I need to format the `DateTime` object in order to display the formatation I would like.

I found [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFSLChart.aspx) that uses the property `ContentStringFormat` of a `ContentControl`, but after some digging I learnt that that property is not available in Silverlight, only on WPF. So I found [another example](http://endofstream.com/charts-creating-custom-style-for-linedatapoint/) that uses a converter, but I can't place the converter definition on the `ResourseDictionary` as I can on a `UserControl`, because a `ResourceDictionary` doesn't have the property `Resources`.. :(

I don't know if I explained myself right, but my question is.. Is it possible to supply a type converter for a static resource in Silverlight?

EDIT - [XAML](http://tinypaste.com/7330ab)

Comment: Could you show us the xaml where you want to use the converter?

Comment: I've tried editing the post but it won't show up the code :/

Comment: Oh. I went ahead and pasted it on TinyPaste :D TY anyway!

Comment: In a ResourceDictionary everything is a resource without having Resources tags enclosing them, so it shouldn't be a problem!

I'm not sure though if you can use a StaticResource as converter parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this SO thread: [Pass value of a field to Silverlight ConverterParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345170/pass-value-of-a-field-to-silverlight-converterparameter)

It has tons of different approaches for getting around converter limitations!